# Prevent ngnix to try resolve remove url to local

Tags: nginx

I need to rewrite remote url to local port (there is app that listen it).

My config:

```
server {
        listen       80;
        server_name  mysite.org;

        location /foo {
            proxy_pass  http://127.0.0.1:8080;
        }
    }
```

Now when I access to `/foo` nginx trying to find `/foo` path in my local app. Like: `http://127.0.0.1:8080/foo`. But I need to force them do not try to get this path, but simply rewrite to `http://127.0.0.1:8080`.

How can I do it?

P.S. I have tried to add tail slash at `http://127.0.0.1:8080/;` but it did not help.

Answer (score 0):

By adding a trailing `/` to `proxy_pass` you are creating a mapping from `/foo` to `/` which will not work for other URIs. For example `/foo/bar` will map to `//bar`. You could solve the problem by using `location /foo/ { ... }`, but then the URI `/foo` would not work and would require a separate fix.

As an alternative to using `proxy_pass` to perform an aliasing function, you can use a `rewrite ... break` instead. See [this document](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_rewrite_module.html#rewrite) for more.

Try:

```
location /foo {
    rewrite ^/foo(?:/(.*))?$ /$1 break;
    proxy_pass  http://127.0.0.1:8080;
}
```

The regular expression captures anything after `/foo/`, but also permits `/foo` to be mapped to `/`. It is broken down as:

```
1  ^     anchor beginning of line
2  /foo  part of URI we need to remove
3  (?:   begin non-capturing group
4  /     part of URI which is optional
5  (.*)  capture anything that must be used to create mapped URI
6  )?    close non-capturing group and make it optional
7  $     anchor end of line
```

We want `$1` to represent everything captured in step 5 hence the use of non-capturing groups. We could have used normal captures and renumbered `$1` to `$2`.

See this [useful resource on regular expressions](http://www.regular-expressions.info/refquick.html).

Comment: Could you explain what `rewrite ^/foo(?:/(.*))?$ /$1 break;` do?